# Запрос с сайта на .aspx

Tags: delphi

На сайте есть

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJLTI0MTE1Nzg3D2QWBAIBD2QWAgIHDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZAIDDw8WAh4EVGV4dGVkZGR2NFVBFeEeY71EBQHL03G6jJXuxQ==">
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="261583EA">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBAL/+amRAgLs0bLrBgLs0fbZDAKM54rGBnsveKYDayDMIAFMQZrF5+2kIAdA">
</div>
```

Идут эти запросы.
Пытался сделать запрос. Но такой вариант не подходит.
Как сделать, так что бы можно было отправлять эти данные?

```
loging.Add('__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUJLTI0MTE1Nzg3D2QWBAIBD2QWAgIHDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZAIDDw8WAh4EVGV4dGVkZGR2NFVBFeEeY71EBQHL03G6jJXuxQ==');
loging.Add('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=261583EA');    loging.Add('__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWBAL/+amRAgLs0bLrBgLs0fbZDAKM54rGBnsveKYDayDMIAFMQZrF5+2kIAdA');
```

Полный код.

```
сonst
  VIEWSTATE = '/wEPDwUJLTI0MTE1Nzg3D2QWBAIBD2QWAgIHDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkZAIDDw8WAh4EVGV4dGVkZGR2NFVBFeEeY71EBQHL03G6jJXuxQ==';
  EVENTVALIDATION = '/wEWBAL/+amRAgLs0bLrBgLs0fbZDAKM54rGBnsveKYDayDMIAFMQZrF5+2kIAdA';
  VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = '261583EA';
var
  loging: TStringList;
  befer :string ;
  name, rep: string;
begin
  loging:= TStringList.Create;
  loging.Add('textbox1='+edt1.Text);
  loging.Add('textbox2='+edt2.Text);
  loging.Add('__VIEWSTATE='+VIEWSTATE);
  loging.Add('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR='+EVENTVALIDATION);
  loging.Add('__EVENTVALIDATION='+VIEWSTATEGENERATOR);
  loging.Add('button1=Зайти на сайт для участников!');
  befer:=idhtp1.Post('http://www.сайт.ru/index.php?id=15',loging);
  if Pos('Добро пожаловать',befer)>0 then
  begin
    lbl1.Caption:='ok';
//            befer := idhtp1.Get('сайи');
//            name := Pars('<li class="post-count"><a href="edit.php?post_type=post">', befer, '</a></li>');
//            rep := Pars(')"><b>', befer, '</b></a></div>');
//            lbl2.Caption:=('=================' + #13#10 + 'Имя: ' + name + #13#10 + 'Репутация:  ' + rep + #13#10 + '=================');
  end
  else lbl1.Caption:='Error';
    mmo1.Lines.Add(befer);
end;
```

Comment: Приведите более полный код. Что такое `loging`? Код непосредственно отправки? Кроме того, судя по тексту - значения полей генерируются в runtime (BASE64 ?), соответственно - статическое задание их у себя в коде может привести не к ожидаемому эффекту.

Comment: Да. это отправка данных

Comment: Ваши константы, скорее всего, не будут работать, вам нужно получать их каждый раз со страницы авторизации.